# SVN log for specific path ignoring history (similar to git log -- file)

Tags: git, svn, logging, version-control

Does Subversion provide a method to view the log of a path, regardless of whether it currently has a file/folder at that path in the current revision? Subversion uses two different specifiers for revisions `@xxxx` (peg revision) and `-rxxxx` (operative revision) to specify the location at a certain revision and the state of that item at another revision (might have been moved in the meanwhile).

Basically, what I'm looking for is the SVN equivalent of the `git log -- path/to/file` command. It will simply print out all commits touching that path, ignoring (i.e. not following) moves.

Doing `svn log -r$rev:$((rev-1) path/to/file@$rev` in a loop seems like overkill (and I'm not sure it will work as intended)

Comment: Actually, I want to list the files/changes inside a directory for a certain revision (not following moves).

Comment: What about `svn log path/to/dir` ?

Comment: @SergeyAzarkevich: this will not work if there has been a different file at that location before. `svn add path/to/dir; svn commit; svn rm path/to/dir; svn commit; svn add path/to/dir; svn commit;`. Log will then not show the original file and is exactly the reason, why I'm asking this question

Comment: No sure.. why you say 'file' but then operate with directory? But anyway, I can propose only solution: `svn log path/to/unchnaged/parent/dir --xml` and then filter XML entries by name. Here `path/to/parent/dir` - path which was not changed. It can be branch root or even repository root.

Comment: I forget: use `-v` option for obtain file paths in xml log

Comment: @SergeyAzarkevich: file or directory does not matter. Unchanged parent dir must be root of repository then, because I don't know which dirs or files were moved or deleted+recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can't see any problem here (for SVN 1.8.*)

Sample **full** repo-log (unrelated changed for path/in/question added)

```
>svn log -v -q file:///Z:/Repo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2015-07-08 15:03:09 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Miracle
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | Badger | 2015-07-08 15:02:06 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/a.txt
   A /trunk/b.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2015-07-08 15:01:09 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/a.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2015-07-08 15:00:13 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/Miracle
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2015-07-08 14:59:17 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Miracle
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2015-07-08 14:57:21 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I want to see only history of **known object** in **known location** (Miracle dir in /trunk) I'll use log for *parent of object* and filter only interesting revisions with `--search` for *name of object*

```
>svn log -q -v file:///Z:/Repo/trunk --search Miracle
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2015-07-08 15:03:09 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Miracle
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2015-07-08 15:00:13 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/Miracle
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2015-07-08 14:59:17 +0500 (Ср, 08 июл 2015)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Miracle
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Will this also find any commits which contain "Miracle" in their log message? Or does `-q` suppress log messages, but `-v` turn on verbose logging, i.e. printing changed paths? This approach might work, but it seems very brittle.

Comment: @knittl - `-q -v` will give you only Miracle in filenames, yes